# Sqlite: select same colume from many tabls

Tags: sqlite, select, union

Let's say we have tables: `t1(_id, url)`, `t2(_id ,url)`, `t3(_id, url)`, ...

I wanna get all url from tables:

```
select url from t1 union select url from t2 union select url from t3 union ...
```

It's fine, but too long if I have 3 more tables. So how can I get all `url` in all table?

Comment: What do you mean by "too long"?

Comment: select url from t1 union select url from t2 union select url from t3 union select url from t4 union select url from t5 union select url from t6 union select url from t100 union ... I wanna do automatically, as I have many tables!

Comment: You might have to do this dynamically then.

Answer (score 1):

If you need data from all tables, you must name all tables somewhere in the `FROM` clause. SQLite has no way of knowing *wich* tables you want to `SELECT` from if you don't name them.

Comment: What about sqlite_master? I select table names from sqlite_master, can I use them in the FROM clause. DO: "select name from sqlite_matser where type = 'table' " GOT: "t1, t2, t3 ..."